# pass fit_params to the cross_val_score in sklearn, it always return nan

Tags: python, scikit-learn

when I pass fit_params to the cross_val_score in **sklearn**, it always return nan

```
parameters = {'n_estimators':100}

model = XGBRegressor()

cv_results = cross_val_score(model,
                             X_train_,
                             y_train_,
                             cv=split,
                             scoring="neg_mean_squared_error",
                             fit_params=parameters,
                             n_jobs=-1)
```

result is: [nan nan nan nan nan]

when I not use the fit_params or pass an empty dict to the fit_params, the result is okay.
But return nan, when pass any parameter to fit_params.
Anyone knows the answer, why?

Answer (score 0):

You get an error because the parameter is not used in `.fit()` method, and if you don't provide parameters you don't run into an error.

`n_estimators` is a parameter used in initializing the model `XGBRegressor()`, that is you can do:

```
model = XGBRegressor(n_estimators = 100)

cv_results = cross_val_score(model,
                             X_train_,
                             y_train_,
                             cv=5,
                             scoring="neg_mean_squared_error")
```

The parameters are passed to the `.fit()` method (see [help page](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html)) are `eval_metric`, `early_stopping_rounds` etc, so for example:

```
model = XGBRegressor(n_estimators = 100)
parameters = {'eval_metric': 'mae'}
    
cv_results = cross_val_score(model,
                             X_train_,
                             y_train_,
                             cv=5,
                             scoring="neg_mean_squared_error",
                             fit_params = parameters)
```

Answer (score 0):

@StupidWolf nailed it ...

I was having a similar issue when I was passing a pipeline to cross_val_score, and solved it by passing the model directly, like in the example here by @StupidWolf.

```
xgb_model = XGBClassifier(**hyperparams,use_label_encoder =False, n_jobs=4)

fit_params={'early_stopping_rounds': 5, 
            'eval_metric': ['logloss'],
            'verbose': False,
            'eval_set': [(X_valid, y_valid)]
           }

# Multiply by -1 since sklearn calculates *negative* RMSE
scores = -1 * cross_val_score(xgb_model, X_train, y_train,
                              cv=5,
                              scoring='neg_root_mean_squared_error',
                              fit_params = fit_params,
                              verbose=1)
```